# CodeIgniter DBForge - Why does it not support create/drop trigger?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Any advice if it is possible to create/drop trigger from CodeIgniter such as Class DBForge? I can only see Create/Drop for Database and Table.

My scenario would be:
When a user register, I need to create a database dedicated for that your user. This include MySQL Event/Trigger Objects.

Comment: Why not extend the DBForge class with your needs? Btw. you don't create a DB-trigger with PHP...

Comment: True, I can't create DB-Trigger with PHP. But I can re-create what the sql statement/instruction inside the trigger I place to PHP. Extending DBForge: I read about DBForge yesterday. I still need to study that on how to extend properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create the trigger, I used to re-create the trigger content withn CodeIgniter Controller together with DBForge Class.